# Using POPEN to store a value to a string using C programming

Tags: c, unix, popen

I am trying to write a C code under UNIX to read the third word from each line of a text, and store it to a string by using POPEN.  However my code is giving me an error (Modifiable lvalue required for assignment operator) at the line inside my while loop.  Here is my code:

```
    int main() {

int license = 0;
char number[100];


FILE *file = popen("grep User results_today.TXT_05012013 > filename", "r");
if ( file != NULL)
{
    char line [128];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)
    {

        number = popen("cut -f3 -d' '", "r");

    }
    fclose (file);

    printf("Hello %s\n", number);
}
```

I know there are a few errors on here as i am still kinda new to C.  But please help me correct them, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
FILE *file = popen("grep User results_today.TXT_05012013 > filename", "r");
```

This will run a `grep` command looking for `User` and redirect the output to the file `filename`.  It will return a `FILE *` that allows you to read the output of this command, but as that output has been redirected, you won't get anything.

```
popen("cut -f3 -d' '", "r");
```

This will run the `cut` command which, as it has no file arguments, will read from stdin and write to stdout which can be read by the `FILE *` that popen returns, but which you aren't doing anything with.

You probably want something more like:

```
char line[128];
int number;
FILE *file = popen("grep User results_today.TXT_05012013 | cut -f3 -d' '", "r");
if (file) {
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file)) {
        if (sscanf(line, "%d", &number) == 1) {
            printf("It's a number: %d\n", number);
        }
    }
    pclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  So it looks like your code will run the grep User and cut command on the text file and output to FILE *file, then use the while loop to output to number?  How come when i run your code it doesn't give me anything?  Not even the "It's a number" part... am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You assign the result of popen to a fixed size char array. This is not possible.

```
number = popen("cut -f3 -d' '", "r");
```

Do it like the first popen -> assign it to FILE *file2

Comment: he should figure that out by himself ;)

Comment: By the way, `getdelim` is a handy way to read the entire input.

Comment: @MircoEllmann Thanks, I kinda guessed that would be the problem.  So now that i have a file called "filename" which i previously used grep User command to extract the info i wanted, is there a different way in using that while loop from my code to extract let's say the 3rd word from each line of the file "filename"?  Thanks.

Comment: You might try to combine the commands with |
grep User results_today.TXT_05012013 | cut -f3 -d' '
You could save the second popen that way. give it a shot...

Answer (score 1):

First of I'm not a C programmer
This is my implementation (with a lot of borrowed lines of course ;) ).
I was just fed up of

```
popen
while fgets
 printf // I want to store in char* got it?
```

So here's the code. It may not be perfect but does the job :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

char* concatenate(char * dest, char * source) {
    char * out = (char *)malloc(strlen(source) + strlen(dest) + 1);

    if (out != NULL) {
            strcat(out, dest);
            strcat(out, source);
    }

    return out;
}

char * executeCmd(char * cmd) {
    FILE *fp;

    int BUFF_SIZE = 1024;

    int size_line; 
    char line[BUFF_SIZE];

    char* results = (char*) malloc(BUFF_SIZE * sizeof(char));

    if (cmd != NULL) {
            /* Open the command for reading. */
            fp = popen(cmd, "r");
            if (fp != NULL) {

            /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
            while (fgets(line, size_line = sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
                    results = concatenate(results, line);
            }
            }
            /* close */
            pclose(fp);
    } // END if cmd ! null

    return results;
}


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    char * out = executeCmd("ls -l");
    printf("%s\n", out);

    return 0;
}
```